# Normalization problem of periodic wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization

So, I want to normalize the eigen wavefunctions of the momentum operator ($-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x)=p\cdot\psi(x)$ where $p$ is a real number).
The solution is $\psi(x)_p=C\cdot e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}px}$ where $C$ is an imaginary or real number and $p$ is real, and now the function is of course not normalizeable. Now I've searched a little and they always wrote something like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi(x)_p\psi_{p'}^*(x)dx=2\pi\delta(p-p')$ and $\phi(x)= \sum_{p,p'}\psi_p(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x')\psi_{p'}(x')dx'$ (I'm not sure where $\phi$ is from), and that you get the Fourier transformation from that, and that my example is not normalizeable in the classical sense.
So I guess I can't get a value for C, since that would be the classical way. But how can I normalize this function then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The momentum operator $P$ doesn't have a normalizable eigenfunction. One writes the eigenfunction as
$$\chi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}$$
The factor comes in here. If we consider the finite boundary, say $L$. Then

$$\chi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}e^{ik_nx}$$
The completeness required:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{L}e^{ik_nx}e^{-ik_{n'}x}=\delta (x-x').\ \ \ \ x,x'\in [-L/2,L/2]$$

Now let $L\rightarrow \infty $ then
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left\{\cdots \right\}\rightarrow \int dn \{\cdots \}=\int dk\left( \frac{dn}{dk}\right)\{\cdots\}$$
where
$$\frac{dn}{dk}=\frac{L}{2\pi}$$
therefore,
$$\int \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{ik_nx}e^{-ik_{n'}x} \ dk=\delta (x-x')$$

where we reorganize
$$\chi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{ik_nx}$$
as desired.

Comment: Okay thank you :) but can you actually work with this equation ? (use it for experiments for example) and is there some kind of "substitute" equation that is normalizeable ? Because in the literature that I've read they always ignored the normalization problem or said that one can normalize the function in a different way

Comment: @Young Kindaichi, Have you missed out a $dk$ in the last integral?

Comment: @petermafai  They are actually not the real physical states because of uncertainty in momentum. But they are easy to work with. There are different methods like box normalization, can be used to normalize these. Or you can also superpose them to make a packet which is normalizable and physically possible.

Comment: @BrendanDarrer I think not :)

Comment: @Young Kindaichi, Yes, because I edited it. It was just a small typo you made! :)

Comment: @BrendanDarrer Thank you Darrer! :)

Comment: @YoungKindaichi  but how does finished normalized equation look like then ? I've never found something like: "$\psi(x)=...$ this is the normalized equation since if you integrate $\psi^2(x)$ over $ \mathbb{R}$ you get $1$".

Comment: @petermafai I don't understand what you just said, Can you rephrase? :)

Comment: @YoungKindaichi so the superpose method I understand ^^ but I dont fully understand the box normalization. You wrote the eigenfunction as $\chi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ik_nx}$ but this function is still not normalizeable since if you integrate $|\chi(x)|^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$ you still get infinity

Comment: The function is normalizable if you consider that particle is inside a box of length L, so that when you integrate over the whole real line, the integral contributes only an infinite length of the region and gives not infinite value. In the superposition method, you can be built a gaussian wavefunction with the help of these eigenfunctions. It's well known that the gaussian function is integrable.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi but if $L$ is finite then its not the same task since in my original task the wavefunction wasnt inside a box. And if you let $L$ go to infinity then you still get a non normalizeable function (the $\chi_n(x)$ in your first answer). And about the superposition method: I thought the result is that $\psi(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\tilde{\psi}(p)e^{ipx}dp$ so the FT. Is it the same that you said in the sense that if you calculte$\tilde{\psi}(p)$ and with that calculte $\psi(x)$ you get the gaussian wavefunction ?

Comment: @petermafai You can always consider particle to be in somebox. Since physically you always have some idea about where does the particle is. It might be in laboratory, or city or earth.

Comment: @patermafai About gaussian function, I mean you can write the gaussian function as superposition of plane waves. See the Wikipedia on wave packet